# not getting the value from contacts contract

Tags: android

i am using contacts contract to take the phone number and name from the phone contacts... how can i take the value(the name and number) of a particular contacts into a variable.....i tried a lot but i was only able to display "DISPLAY_NAME and DATA_1".....

Comment: post your current code and describe where its failing.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the tutorial at http://www.app-solut.com/blog/2011/03/working-with-the-contactscontract-to-query-contacts-in-android/ which covers how to query all contacts and basic information like the name or phone number for these contacts.